When I try a request from my React Native app, I encounter an AxiosNetworkError
Title:
Axios Network Error when uploading an image to Node.js backend (working fine in Postman but failing in React Native)
Question:
I have a full-stack application where I’m using React Native on the frontend and Node.js with Express on the backend. The backend successfully processes an image via a POST request in Postman, but when I try the same request from my React Native app, I encounter an AxiosNetworkError.
Frontend (React Native):
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button, Image, View, StyleSheet, Text, Alert } from "react-native";
import * as ImagePicker from "expo-image-picker";
import axios from "axios";

export default function ImagePickerExample() {
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
  const [insights, setInsights] = useState("");

  const pickImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
    });

    if (!result.canceled) {
      setImage(result.assets[0].uri);
    }
  };

  const getInsights = async () => {
    if (!image) {
      Alert.alert("Please select an image first");
      return;
    }

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("image", {
      uri: image,
      type: "image/jpeg",
      name: "image.jpg",
    });

    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        "http://<your-local-ip>:3000/api/v1/image/process-image",
        formData,
        { headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" } }
      );

      if (response.data.success) {
        setInsights(response.data.data);
      } else {
        Alert.alert("Error", "Could not retrieve insights.");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error uploading image:", error);
      Alert.alert("Upload Failed", "There was an error processing the image.");
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button title="Pick an image" onPress={pickImage} />
      {image && <Image source={{ uri: image }} style={styles.image} />}
      <Button title="Get Insights" onPress={getInsights} />
      {insights && <Text>Insights: {insights}</Text>}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  image: {
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    marginTop: 20,
  },
});

Backend (Node.js with Express):
import cors from "cors";
import uploadImageRoutes from "./routes/uploadImage.routes.js";

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

// Middleware
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

// Routes
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("Hello World!");
});

app.use("/api/v1/image", uploadImageRoutes);

// Start server
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
});

Image Processing Route (Backend):
import express from "express";
import { upload } from "../middlewares/multer.js";
import { GoogleGenerativeAI } from "@google/generative-ai";
import fs from "fs";

const router = express.Router();
const genAI = new GoogleGenerativeAI("your-gemini-api-key");
const model = genAI.getGenerativeModel({ model: "gemini-1.5-pro" });

router.route("/process-image").post(upload.single("image"), async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const imagePath = req.file.path;

    const generatedResponse = await model.generateContent([
      "What's in this image?",
      {
        inlineData: {
          data: Buffer.from(fs.readFileSync(`./${imagePath}`)).toString("base64"),
          mimeType: "image/jpeg",
        },
      },
    ]);

    res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      data: generatedResponse.response.text(),
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: error.message });
  }
});

export default router;

Multer Middleware:
import multer from "multer";

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "./");
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname);
  },
});

export const upload = multer({ storage });

Problem:

The API is working perfectly fine when I use Postman with form-data (image upload).
However, when I try to upload an image from my React Native app using Axios, I get the error: AxiosError: Network Error.

Steps Taken:

IP Address: I’ve updated the backend URL in the frontend code with my local IP address (http://<your-local-ip>:3000), not localhost or 127.0.0.1, because I’m testing on a physical device.
CORS: I’ve added CORS middleware in the backend to allow cross-origin requests.
Firewall: I’ve disabled the firewall temporarily to ensure it's not blocking the connection.
Network: Both my mobile device and the backend server are on the same Wi-Fi network.

What I've Tried:

Testing the API in Postman works, but when trying it in React Native, the error persists.
I’ve added console logs and catch blocks to identify issues in Axios, but still facing the same issue.

Any help on what could be causing this issue or how to debug the problem further would be greatly appreciated.

Let me know if you need any more details!
